# Prove divergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ((-1)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need help finding a smaller series so that I can show that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ((-1)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{n})$ is diverging. I thought maybe we can take $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} ((-1)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ which is smaller than that, but I realized straight away, that this series is converging.

Is there anyone who could help me? I would be very grateful.

Comment: Is the sum of a convergent and divergent series convergent or divergent?

Comment: If $\sum_{n}x_n<\infty $ and $\sum_{n}y_n=+\infty $, then $\sum_{n}(x_n+y_n)=\sum_{n}x_n+\sum_{n}y_n=+\infty $.

Comment: Were the series $$ \displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}  \ (-1)^n  \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} + \frac{1}{n} \right) \ \ , $$ it _would_ be convergent as an alternating series.  But adding a "bare" harmonic series to the other series is going to make the sum diverge, regardless of whether that series converges or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $a_n=(-1)^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $b_n=\frac{1}{n}$ and $c_n=a_n+b_n$

If $\sum c_n$ converges then as $\sum a_n$ converges (by Leibnitz test),so $\sum b_n=\sum(c_n-a_n)$ converges but this is not true as harmonic series diverges.

Comment: That test is usually known as the alternating series test.